# What is the default database mapping type for a String in Grails?

Tags: grails

If I have a domain object that looks like this:

```
class Note {
    Long id
    String content
}
```

What kind of datatype is "content" going to be mapped to in a database, by default? Is it a varchar? How many characters?

Comment: There's no need to declare the `id` field - it's auto-created for you by Grails (along with the `version` field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varchar(255) is the default without any constraints for a String.